# How can I change the size of the h2 month header on full calendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am having trouble with the h2 month header on full calendar. 14px is ridiculously small and I cannot work out how to make the month title bigger without changing the size of the other items.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [the sample](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) from FullCalendar website, this simple CSS rule shall be enough:

```
.fc h2 {
   font-size: 20px;
}
```